# How to load the latest data model generated using API in RASA on server?

Tags: rasa-nlu

I am able to train the data model using train API endpoint in RASA but created data model is not getting loaded automatically.

Is there a way to train and load the data model without restarting the server?

[image: Traing Command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recently trained model is automatically loaded upon the next `/parse` request to that project.

> By default the latest trained model for the project will be loaded.

taken from here: https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/http/#id4

If you have more information to suggest it isn't be loaded please add that to your question.

Comment: The latest model got loaded but previous data model did not got removed.{
            "available_models": [
                "model_20180808-115935",
                "model_20180806-183933",
                "model_20180808-115221",
                "model_20180814-202029",
                "model_20180810-152456",
                "model_20180816-141416"
            ],
         **   "loaded_models": [
                "model_20180814-202029",
                "model_20180816-141416"
            ]
        }**

Comment: Yeah, you can unload models from memory with the `/delete` endpoint, but they aren't physically deleted.